# Gstreamer element dmairesizer video shift

Tags: gstreamer

I am writing a gstreamer pipeline on leopard board imaging board. I am using dmairesizer element for video capture and later encoding (h.264) but the dmairesizer is shifting video as shown in the photo attached. Left part is shown on right and vice versa.

[image: Photo illustrating issue]

Gstreamer pipeline is as follows

```
gst-launch -e v4l2src input-src=composite chain-ipipe= true always-copy=false queue-size=6 ! dmaiaccel ! video/x-raw-yuv, format=\(fourcc\)NV12 , height=576, width=720 ! priority ! queue ! dmaienc_h264 targetbitrate=2000000 bytestream=true copyOutput=false single-nalu=true encodingpreset=2 ratecontrol=2 ! queue ! dmaiperf ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=199.200.15.61 port= 6666 sync=false enable-last-buffer=false
```

I am using vlc to stream mpegtsmux stream.

Without dmairesizer element video doesn't shift.

```
gst-launch -e v4l2src input-src=composite chain-ipipe=false always-copy=false queue-size=6 ! dmaiaccel ! dmairesizer ! priority ! queue ! dmaienc_h264 targetbitrate=2000000 bytestream=true copyOutput=false single-nalu=true encodingpreset=2 ratecontrol=2 ! queue ! dmaiperf ! mpegtsmux ! udpsink host=199.200.15.61 port= 6666 sync=false enable-last-buffer=false
```

I have posted this simple problem on multiple forums but to no avail.

Comment: Website not allowing to upload the photo as I am new user to this website.

Comment: Upload it to imgur and post the URL in a comment here, then I'll add it to the question for you.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/mrASR40

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled upon the same issue. If you are sending the dataptr you need to do a Buffer.map to get the correct dataptr. For example in C# :
sample.Buffer.Map(out map, MapFlags.Read);
map.DataPtr will get you thecorrect memory address to pass to VLC